# Apache - RewriteRule with exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We recently moved a whole site to a new url.  We have added a temporary redirect to a page that advises the user of the new site location. Our redirect is this and it works :

```
RewriteRule         ^ncr/oec/       /404/oec-bce.php
```

But we have one application which resides at /ncr/oec/apps/ that we don't want to redirect as it hasn't been moved yet.

How do we add an exception for just that application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude the uri, just put the following condition above your rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ncr/oec/apps/?$
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem.  I can't believe it was such an easy fix! :-)